# subview didn't call dealloc when superview(UIViewController) dealloc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, dealloc

I was confuse with memory management of removeFromSuperview.

Here is my code:

```
MySubView *tMySubView = [[MySubView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
tMySubView.center = self.view.center;
tMySubView.tag = 1111;
[self.view addSubview:tMySubView];
[tMySubView release];
```

"self" is UIViewController.

When "self" call dealloc but MySubView didn't call dealloc.

I know addSubView retainCount +1.

So I try add [tMySubView removeFromSuperview] in "self" dealloc

And MySubView dealloc was called...

Should I add [subView removeFromSuperview]; when superView dealloc?

Or superView removeFromSuperview ,it will automaticly call subView's removeFromSuperview...?

I can't figure it out. :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It means that self.view is not properly released. It will remove all it's subviews only in case when it is deallocated.

Check your loadView method (where you're probably initialize it). If it looks like this:

```
-(void) loadView {
   self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
}
```

then you've got leak and have to rewrite it like this:

```
-(void) loadView {
   self.view = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

OR

```
-(void) loadView {
   UIView* v = [[UIView alloc] init];
   self.view = v;
   [v release];
}
```

Also check all the places where you're accessing self.view and make sure you're not over-retaining it.

Comment: MyViewController *tMyViewController = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
 [tNavigationController pushViewController:tMyViewController animated:YES];I write like this.

Comment: don't confuse viewcontroller and it's view.

Comment: How is the view created? In loadView or in a XIB?

Comment: if you're loading view controller from xib, then everything is done automatically. Do you have loadView in your code for that view controller?

Comment: Hi ~ I add subView in viewDidLoad , ganerated by code instead IB. Thanks. :)

Comment: In loadView I write nothing @@.